# Mongodb aggregation nested lookup

Tags: mongodb, nested, lookup, aggregation

I have 3 collections as follows:

GroupRoles Collection:

```
//1
{
    "_id": ObjectId("62a384ee0c4dbafc64000fba"),
    "name": "GroupRole template 1",
    "groupRoles": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("6298503f8a31000024002107"),
            "members": [
                ObjectId("629e1bb117366c39bc7d78e1")
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("629850368a31000024002106"),
            "members": [
                ObjectId("629ee6d502877d0f93f5dabe"),
                ObjectId("629ee6d002877d0f93f5dab8")
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("6298502f8a31000024002105"),
            "members": [ ]
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("629850288a31000024002104"),
            "members": [ ]
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("6298501f8a31000024002103"),
            "members": [ ]
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("629850128a31000024002102"),
            "members": [ ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Role Collections:

// 1 {"_id": ObjectId("629850128a31000024002102"), "type": 1, "name": "Role 1",}

// 2 {"_id": ObjectId("6298501f8a31000024002103"), "type": 1, "name": "Role 2",}

// 3 {"_id": ObjectId("629850288a31000024002104"), "type": 1, "name": "Role 3",}

// 4 {"_id": ObjectId("6298502f8a31000024002105"), "type": 1, "name": "Role 4",}

// 5 {"_id": ObjectId("629850368a31000024002106"), "type": 1, "name": "Role 5",}

// 6 {"_id": ObjectId("6298503f8a31000024002107"), "type": 1, "name": "Role 6",}

and User Collection:

// 1 {"_id": ObjectId("629e1bb117366c39bc7d78e1"), "email": "abc1@gmail.com", "name": "user 01"}

// 2 {"_id": ObjectId("629ee6d502877d0f93f5dabe"), "email": "abc2@gmail.com", "name": "user 02"}

// 3 {"_id": ObjectId("629ee6d002877d0f93f5dab8"), "email": "abc3@gmail.com", "name": "user 03"}

How can select GroupRoles with output format like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("62a384ee0c4dbafc64000fba"),
    "name": "GroupRole template 1",
    "groupRoles": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("6298503f8a31000024002107"),
            "type": 1,
            "name": "Role 6",
            "members": [
                {
                    "_id": ObjectId("629e1bb117366c39bc7d78e1"),
                    "email": "abc1@gmail.com",
                    "name": "user 01"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("629850368a31000024002106"),
            "type": 1,
            "name": "Role 5",
            "members": [
                {
                    "_id": ObjectId("629ee6d502877d0f93f5dabe"),
                    "email": "abc2@gmail.com",
                    "name": "user 02"
                },
                {
                    "_id": ObjectId("629ee6d002877d0f93f5dab8"),
                    "email": "abc3@gmail.com",
                    "name": "user 03"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("6298502f8a31000024002105"),
            "type": 1,
            "name": "Role 4",
            "members": [ ]
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("629850288a31000024002104"),
            "type": 1,
            "name": "Role 3",
            "members": [ ]
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("6298501f8a31000024002103"),
            "type": 1,
            "name": "Role 2",
            "members": [ ]
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("629850128a31000024002102"),
            "type": 1,
            "name": "Role 1",
            "members": [ ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried aggregation and lookup, but it didn't get the results I wanted.

*here is my aggregation query*
The list of members is not in the correct index of groupRoles

```
[
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'roles', 
      'localField': 'groupRoles._id', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'temp_roles'
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'users', 
      'localField': 'groupRoles.members', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'temp_users'
    }
  }, {
    '$addFields': {
      'groupRoles': {
        '$map': {
          'input': '$groupRoles.members', 
          'as': 'mems', 
          'in': {
            'members': {
              '$filter': {
                'input': '$temp_users', 
                'as': 'temu', 
                'cond': {
                  '$in': [
                    '$$temu._id', '$$mems'
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$addFields': {
      'groupRoles': {
        '$map': {
          'input': {
            '$zip': {
              'inputs': [
                '$groupRoles', '$temp_roles'
              ]
            }
          }, 
          'in': {
            '$mergeObjects': '$$this'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$unset': [
      'temp_roles', 'temp_users'
    ]
  }, {
    '$facet': {
      'metadata': [
        {
          '$group': {
            '_id': null, 
            'total': {
              '$sum': 1
            }
          }
        }
      ], 
      'data': []
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'data': {
        '_id': 1, 
        'name': 1, 
        'groupRoles': {
          '_id': 1, 
          'type': 1, 
          'name': 1, 
          'members': {
            '_id': 1, 
            'name': 1, 
            'email': 1
          }
        }
      }, 
      'total': {
        '$arrayElemAt': [
          '$metadata.total', 0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

please help me find the solution.

Comment: Perhaps share your aggregate query to the question, so we can try to reproduce and detect the root cause.

Comment: @YongShun i added the error statement. my members list is in the wrong place in groupRoles.
it not mapped with role id.

Comment: [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IJ9fdRc690L). The output data look the same as your expected data. Can you further explain what the "list of members is not in the correct index of groupRoles" mean? Is it order by sequence based on the id in original `groupRoles.members`?

Comment: @YongShun Oh sorry, I omitted the value when I wrote the question, I edited the data in the question.
Member list of result not mapped with role id.

Comment: [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pmQdvzkDTSl) in my correct result user :"629e1bb117366c39bc7d78e1" is member of role "6298503f8a31000024002107". but query return user "629e1bb117366c39bc7d78e1" is member of role "629850128a31000024002102".

Answer (score 0):

Revise your query and thanks for the hints.

The issue is on `$zip`, which I think this operator is not suitable. You can check the [behavior of `$zip`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/#behavior).

Combine both `$addFields` stages into one.

Iterate each value in `groupRoles` and with `$mergeObjects` for

1. Current iterate value.
2. The first match document from the `temp_roles` array by matching `_id`.
3. The document with `members` array.

```
db.groupRoles.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "roles",
      "localField": "groupRoles._id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "temp_roles"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "groupRoles.members",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "temp_users"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "groupRoles": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$groupRoles",
          "as": "gr",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$gr",
              {
                $first: {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$temp_roles",
                    "as": "r",
                    "cond": {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$gr._id",
                        "$$r._id"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "members": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$temp_users",
                    "as": "mem",
                    "cond": {
                      "$in": [
                        "$$mem._id",
                        "$$gr.members"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "temp_roles",
      "temp_users"
    ]
  },
  
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E4NvqWL9ZWP)